# how to update image in a different form c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Beginner here, I'm trying to update the image and the image's name from a different form and it's not updating. Also it doesn't give any errors. Is there something wrong in the code?

Form 2. this is where i update

```
  private void btnStockEdit_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            string qry = "Update SMStocksTb Set SmStockImgName=@SmStockImgName,SmStockImage=@SmStockImage where SmStockId=@SmStockId";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, sqlCon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SmStockId", SmStockId);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SmStockImgName", txtUPImgName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SmStockImage", Savephoto());

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlCon.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Update  Successfully","Updated",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
    private byte[] Savephoto()
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        pbxUpdateImg.Image.Save(ms, pbxUpdateImg.Image.RawFormat);
        return ms.GetBuffer();
    }
```

**Form1 ** this is where i open form 2 after selecting a row in datagrid

```
        private void btnStockEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        SMStockUpdateForm cfrmStockUpdateForm = new SMStockUpdateForm();
        try
        {
            if (StockListDG.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
            {
             SmStockId = Convert.ToInt32(StockListDG.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());


                 cfrmStockUpdateForm.txtUPImgName.Text = StockListDG.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
                byte[] ImageArray = (byte[])StockListDG.CurrentRow.Cells[12].Value;

                if (ImageArray.Length == 0)
                    cfrmStockUpdateForm.pbxUpdateImg.Image = DefaultImage;

                else
                {
                    ImageByteArray = ImageArray;
                    cfrmStockUpdateForm.pbxUpdateImg.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(ImageArray));
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        cfrmStockUpdateForm.ShowDialog(this);

        if (isWindowOpen == false)
        {
            this.ParentForm.Opacity = 100;
        }



    }
```

Comment: Is the SQL code relevant to your question? If so, how?

Comment: The reason I ask about the SQL code is because your question talks about updating an image on one form from another form, yet your "update" code is an SQL update. It's not really clear what you're asking (to me at least). I've tried to help you by clarifying what you're asking, but if you're not willing to help us help you, then I'm out.

Answer (score 2):

You should learn how to send data between two forms. From form1 you should only send the name of image and in form two should bind it according to its name you received from form1